# PHP/SQL Form: Inserting Improperly

Tags: php, sql

I'm new to PHP/SQL, and I'm attempting to create a form that would insert the given data into a formatted table. After fiddling with it for a bit, I have managed to get the primary functions working, however, it seems my script is inserting data one column over, and I can't for the life of me understand why. Here is the script I've made:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -d display_errors=STDOUT
<?php
  // begin this XHTML page
  print('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>');
  print("\n");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Accessing a SQLite 3 Database using PHP</title> 
</head>
<body>
<p>
<?php 


$database = "students.db";          


try  
{     
     $db = new SQLite3($database);
}
catch (Exception $exception)
{
    echo '<p>There was an error connecting to the database!</p>';

    if ($db)
    {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }

}


// define tablename + fieldnames
$table = "bruins";
$field1 = "name";
$field2 = "sid";
$field3 = "gpa";


// Create the table
$sql= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
$field1 varchar(100),
$field2 int(9),
$field3 decimal(3,1)
)";
$result = $db->query($sql);

print "<h3>Creating the table</h3>";
print "<p>$sql</p>";

// Extract SID and GPA from the $_GET data.
$name = $_GET['name'];

$SID = $_GET['SID'];

$GPA = $_GET['GPA'];


//  Insert a new record to DB with name = $name, sid = $SID and gpa = $GPA 
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($field1, $field2, $field3) 
  VALUES ('$name', '$SID', '$GPA')";


print "Inserting a new record to the bruins table the command I am using is:</br>";
print "$sql";
$result = $db->query($sql);


// print an XHTML table to display the current table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
$result = $db->query($sql);


print "<table border='border'>\n";
print "  <tr>\n";
print "     <th>" . $field1 . "</th>\n";
print "     <th>" . $field2 . "</th>\n";
print "     <th>" . $field3 . "</th>\n";
print "  </tr>\n";

// obtain the results from the SELECT query as an array holding a record
while($record = $result->fetchArray())
{  
  print "  <tr>\n";
  print "  <td>" . $record[$field1] . "<td>\n";
  print "  <td>" . $record[$field2] . "<td>\n";
  print "  <td>" . $record[$field3] . "<td>\n";
  print "  </tr>\n";
}

print "</table>\n";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon submitting the data, the table is created, but all SID strings are in the GPA column, and the GPA strings are placed into their own blank column. Any advice/insight would be great :-)

Comment: At first sight it looks correct, but can you post the results printed in screen? This may not be it, but you're not closing the <td> correctly, close them with </td>

Comment: It was really just that.... closing the <td></td> tags properly. I feel ridiculous lol. Thank you!!

Comment: Awesome @demboiz, I'm glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting the answer here again just in case somebody doesn't see it in the comments.
Closing the s properly at the end of the code resolved the problem :)